# Chrome debugger: Doesn't show breakpoints properly

Tags: google-chrome, breakpoints, javascript-debugger

since a few days the Chrome JavaScript debugger doesn't show me the position of a breakpoint automatically. It correctly pauses, but it doesn't select the right tab in 'sources' and it doesn't jump to the code. Sometimes it doesn't even load the *.js-file. Only if press F10 or F11 now, everything works as expected (chrome shows correct file and line). That's bad because a don't want any code to be executed before I have inspected the breakpoint.

I often have more then 20 different source files loaded and it's very frustrating to manually scroll through all them to search for the highlighted line...

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Chrome version: 31.0.1650.57 m
System: Win7 Pro x64

Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. 
Google Chrome 35.0.1916.114 (Official Build 270117) m;
OS Windows ;
debugger stops at breakpoint but doesn't shift the focus to the breakpoint, it's hard to tell where did the code stopped. Have you figured out any solution ?

Comment: This is still happening 8 months later. Anyone seeing anything different?